# In supervised machine learning, why exactly shouldn't my input variables be correlated with my target variables?

Tags: feature-selection

I understand the reasons why my input variables should not be correlated to each other (multicolinearity). However, I also read that my input variables should not be correlated with the target variable either.

What is the reason behind this? Don't input variables that are somewhat correlated with target variables gives us more information on how to better predict on the target variable?

Please enlighten me!

Comment: Read where?  Do you have a reference?

Comment: Wherever you read that, do not waste more time reading that source, find something better.